# How to run a program with arguments with MONO?

Tags: shell, mono, command-line-arguments

I have a program that receives input arguments:

```
$ myProgram.exe -arg1 -arg2 -arg3
```

in Windows that works just fine. I want to run that through MONO in linux. How do I do that?

```
$ mono myProgram.exe
```

runs the program, but how do I pass the `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` to `myProgram.exe` using MONO?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would have been a better question if you told us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [mono wiki](http://mono.wikia.com/wiki/Man_mono), the syntax for invoking mono is:

```
mono [options] file [arguments...]
```

I think that `options` are options to mono, while `arguments` are arguments to the program you want to run.  So just do this:

```
mono myProgram.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

You might also be able to execute it without explicitly calling mono.  This works on some platforms and not on others:

```
./myProgram.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Alright, that's what I tried... But it's not working in the cluster where I'm trying to run the program... Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK! My bad... I'm dumb! That's it! Tks